Why does a result set change when joining two derived tables after filtering data
Two queries almost identical give different results see below just by filtering:
Why is this query getting the results I want:
select
z.fnd_entity, z.fnd_fund, z.fnd_account,z.fnd_amount, x.exp_entity, x.exp_parent,z.fnd_parent, x.exp_amount
from
(
select
a1.entity fnd_entity, a1.funding_type fnd_fund,ha.parent fnd_parent,a1.account fnd_account,sum(a1.amount) fnd_amount
from table_a a1, table_b ha
where a1.account = ha.account
and a1.b = '2025'
and a1.a = 'F'


When I put this criteria in the query I get the expected results.  But
of course with only a limited amount of data when I want to do this
against the whole table
and a1.entity = '1'
and a1.funding_type in ('G1','G15')
group by a1.entity, a1.funding_type, a1.account,ha.parent
) 
z
left join
(
select
a.entity exp_entity, ha.parent exp_parent, sum(a.amount) exp_amount
from table_a a, table_b ha
where a.account = ha.account
and a.b = '2025'
and a.a = 'E'
and a.entity = '1'
group by a.entity,ha.parent
) x
on (substr(x.exp_parent,2,2) = substr(z.fnd_account,2,2) and x.exp_entity = z.fnd_entity)
order by x.exp_entity, z.fnd_fund, x.exp_parent,z.fnd_parent
;

Results, notice the bottom row, with the null results based on the join:
|1|G1|911990|5574605|1|E11|F11|5640568
|1|G1|912990|2777174|1|E12|F12|2810041
|1|G15|900990|98830  | null  |null|F00| null

But this query against the same data does not return any rows from the left side that are not in the right side?
select
z.fnd_entity, z.fnd_fund, z.fnd_account,z.fnd_amount, x.exp_entity, x.exp_parent,z.fnd_parent, x.exp_amount
from
(
select
a1.entity fnd_entity, a1.funding_type fnd_fund,ha.parent fnd_parent,a1.account fnd_account,sum(a1.amount) fnd_amount
from table_a a1, table_b ha
where a1.account = ha.account
and a1.b = '2025'
and a1.a = 'F'
group by a1.entity, a1.funding_type, a1.account,ha.parent
) 
z
left join
(
select
a.entity exp_entity, ha.parent exp_parent, sum(a.amount) exp_amount
from table_a a, table_b ha
where a.account = ha.account
and a.b = '2025'
and a.a = 'E'
group by a.entity,ha.parent
) x
on (substr(x.exp_parent,2,2) = substr(z.fnd_account,2,2) and x.exp_entity = z.fnd_entity)
order by x.exp_entity, z.fnd_fund, x.exp_parent,z.fnd_parent
;

Results, notice all I've done is remove the filter, but same tables, now no null results from the join:
|1|G1|911990|5574605    |1  | E11 | F11 | 5640568
|1|G1|912990|2777174    |1  | E12 | F12 | 2810041
|12|G12|900990|2127     |1  | E00 | F00 | 2127
|12|G12|911990|14352    |12 | E11 | F11 | 14352
|12|G12|930990|1971     |12 | E30 | F30 | 1971


Please [edit] the question and include a [MRE] with: the CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements (that we can copy/paste and execute) for your sample data so that we can replicate your issues.

just wild guess but in the 2nd query the same table is referenced twice with the same alias "ha" in 2 places within the same query. Not saying that makes a difference but it's definitely not a good practice. What happens if you change that ?

A [mre] being minimal is extremely important. Please read the link, as well as [ask]...  We should also be able to run your example, so that requires sample input data, executable code, and both desired and actual results.

Without some saple data it's hard to tell, but it looks like you have issues due to agregations and groupings combined with possibly wide join conditions between two aggregations.
-- join condition between two aggregated subqueries
ON ( substr(x.exp_parent,2,2) = substr(z.fnd_account,2,2) and 
     x.exp_entity = z.fnd_entity
   )

... this will join for same entity all rows having common 2nnd & 3rd character within account & parent ...
Your aggregations,  lets call them F and E queries, have different Group By clauses (not saying it's wrong) where E query is grouped by entity and parent. Now, when you aply your filters:
and a1.entity = '1'
and a1.funding_type in ('G1','G15')

... you significantly narrowed the set of rows to be compared and get your result that shows a missmatched G15 fund_type  ...
When you remove the filter the set of rows is wider and, maybe, your E query aggregation and grouping as well as Join ON conditions made a join with some other account/parent combination having the same 2nd & 3rd character putting G15 as matched somewhere furder in the resultset.

take a look through your unfiltered resultset and see where G15 row is !!!

Once, again, it's impossible to tell without sample data but it could be that filtered data shows missmatch and wider data does have a match  ( good or bad, but a match ).
